# Firebase function that reads data for a certain day using wrong dates because of firestore timestamp

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, timestamp

I have the following code that takes in a date thats suppose to use that date to get values from firebase. I currently set the dates to 00:00:00 - 23:59:59:999. But the timestamp values are adding +02:00 when saving to firebase, and retrieving the values.

What must i do to force 00:00:00 - 23:59:59:999 when converting dates to firestore timestamps.

See example code below. This is the functions thats either being called from a pubsub, or manually with a post call:

```js
async function generateDailyStats(date) {
    let startDate;
    let endDate;

    // Used by cron to get yesterdays stats every morning
    if (date === undefined) {
        startDate = new Date();
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 1);
        startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

        endDate = new Date();
        endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() - 1);
        endDate.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
    } else { // Manually generate stats for a day
        startDate = new Date(date);
        startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

        endDate = new Date(date);
        endDate.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
    }

    console.log(startDate); // 2023-01-30T00:00:00.000Z
    console.log(endDate);   // 2023-01-30T23:59:59.999Z

    const usersCreatedYesterday = await getCountOfCollectionItemsCreatedForDates('users', 'createdAt', startDate, endDate);


     let jsonString = {
        date: startDate,
        usersCreated: usersCreatedYesterday
    };

    await saveDailyUsageToFirebase(jsonString, startDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10));

    return jsonString;

}
```

This counts the documents in a collection that meets the timestamp criteria:

```js
async function getCountOfCollectionItemsCreatedForDates(collectionName, timestampField, start, end) {

    const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection(collectionName)
        .where(timestampField, '>=', start) // this starts incorrectly from 2023-01-30T02:00:00.000Z
        .where(timestampField, '<', end)
        .get();

    if (snapshot.empty) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return snapshot.size;
    }
}
```

This saves the data to a stats collection for future reference

```js
async function saveDailyUsageToFirebase(stats, date) {
    await admin.firestore().collection('daily_stats').doc(date).set(stats, {merge: true});
}
```

The json in the return string is correct:

```
{
    "date": "2023-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "usersCreated": 4,
}
```

But the date saved in firebase is wrong / accounting for timezone:
[image]

Causing this guy to not be counted:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried passing the date object itself in the query instead of Firestore timestamp with `fromDate()`?

Comment: Thank you, i tried to no avail. For some reason i cant explain, the json thats being returned are correct. But the lookup and the value saved in the db is +02:00

Comment: I doubt it could be timezone issue on where the cloud function is running iirc. Can you try constructing datetime objects using a package like Luxon as I've explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74358192/13130697)? i.e. getting UTC start of day and not current timezone;s

Comment: @TheunodeBruin Note that dates are stored in UTC in Firestore but shown with your browser time zone when displayed in the console.

Comment: Have you tried fetching the timestamp to try to convert it? Sample code: // to get as date const date = new TimeStamp(yourTimeStamp.seconds , yourTimeStamp.nanoseconds).toDate(); // to get as string const date = new TimeStamp(yourTimeStamp.seconds , yourTimeStamp.nanoseconds).toDate().toDateString();

Comment: I have accepted that whats displayed in the browser is according to my locale, and that the timestamps saved are correct. The user mentioned above actually downloaded the app January 31, 23:58:45. Because the time got converted in my browser it got adjusted to display according to my time zone so it looked like 1 feb